# NullPointerException getDefaultSharedPreferences()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I keep getting NullPointerException on this line:

```
SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I ran some things through and I believe that I have the wrong context as it is in a subpackage of the main package so I don't think it can reference the XML preference files. I have used this in class's that are in the main package with no trouble but for some reason this causes an exception.

Full code:

```
package schoolBook.Icestone.Expandable;

import schoolBook.Icestone.Days;
import schoolBook.Icestone.Main;
import schoolBook.Icestone.SetPreference;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Lesson1 extends Lessons {

    public Lesson1(String name) {
        super(name);
        // setGroup(" " + Days.getLessonarray(0) + " ");
        String key = "W" + Main.getWeek() + "_" + SetPreference.xmlday + "_L"
                + SetPreference.xmllesson + "_Lesson";
        System.out.println(key);
        try {
            SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String group = myPreference.getString(key, "def");
            setGroup(" " + group + " ");
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            setGroup(" " + Days.getLessonarray(0) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

`Lessons` class extends Activity so think that may be the source of my problem but im not sure.

File structure:

Icestone

- Main.class and some other classes that use shared preference and it works fine

  - Lessons package (Lesson1 & Lesson are in this package)
- XML folder with the preferences in it

if anyone could help shed some light on this problem it would be much appreciated

Comment: Since the poster did not accept an answer - As staed in the answers the problem is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this inside the constructor.

If it extends Activity Class it should't has a constructor, you need to handle that inside the oncreate method.

Comment: im confused, do you mean i need an onCreate method in this class or in the class that it extends?

Comment: Does your class extends Activity? if yes you can override the method onCreate() and put your code inside this method, please reffer to [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: Lesson extends Activity and Lesson1 extends Lesson. Ill try it out and see what happens   

EDIT: added OnCreate to Lesson1 and still didn't work, couldnt pass 

 SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

to the constructor

Comment: forget about using a constructor inside this class!!! An activity is instantiated by the system, all your code should be in one of the methods described in the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: ahh..and when you override a method like onCreate() or onResume() you MUST call the parent's method like:
`super.onCreate()`

Comment: Im sorry but im compleatly lost, i need these constructors in order to form my ExpandableList and i dont see how i can encorperate onCreate() into it to allow me to get the preferences.

Comment: Im Still stuck on this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated