# Why getApplicationContext() in constructor of Activity throws null pointer exception?

Tags: android, constructor, nullpointerexception, android-context

After some time spent bug hunting it turns out that :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity { // BaseActivity extends Activity

    public MainActivity() {
        super();
        getApplicationContext(); // NPE here
    }
}
```

Why ? Where is this documented ?
Froyo

Comment: Never implement a constructor on an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare: It was on a `service` actually :D Care to provide some input - links - source links. Anyway shouldn't this be/isn't this documented somewhere ?

Comment: You're trying to get a value that hasn't been instantiated by the framework yet. That's why you have methods like `onCreate()`, where it's safe to use these values.

Comment: @dmon:should be in the docs - it's different to have something return null and throw null - maybe fill an issue ?

Comment: "It was on a service actually" -- the code that you have pasted above shows an activity implementing a constructor. "Anyway shouldn't this be/isn't this documented somewhere ?" -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle) "Called when the activity is starting. This is where most initialization should go: calling setContentView(int) to inflate the activity's UI, using findViewById(int) to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI, calling managedQuery() to retrieve cursors for data being displayed, etc."

Comment: Nope, not an issue. Any method can throw a NullPointerException, it doesn't have to be declared. And, even IF it returned null instead of throwing a NullPointerException, you would end up throwing the exception yourself later when you tried to use said null value. Btw, returning a null and throwing a NPE are conceptually different things.

Comment: That being said, yes, it should be called out more. The rule is to wait until the first lifecycle method (`onCreate()` or `onReceive()`) when implementing any component.

Comment: @CommonsWare:I was calling `Class.newInstance()` on a Service implementation to have access to some variables and got that - I know I have posted an activity above - it should be the same with all Context derived classes - I posted it like this for clarity - code was much more convoluted - `getSystemService()` throws also btw - thanks for link

Comment: @dmon: I know - and no I think this behavior is _counterintuitive_. A method is not supposed to throw an unchecked exception except A) if it has a bug or B) one uses it the wrong way - but this _wrong way_ should be in the docs - as is in most api classes in java (throws NPE if argument is null etc) - and I usually check for null so I would (probably) not fall for null return value (I know it's different from a NPE!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wait for the end of `onCreate` to call this method.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity { 

    public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super(savedInstanceState);
        getApplicationContext(); //activity has a context now
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out - my problem is not that `getApplicationContext();` returns null but that it _throws_. Where is this documented is my question - and possibly some theory on the matter :) - I believe many have fell to the lack of docs on this one - would qualify for a bug report

Comment: Check at the source code of Activity. My guess is that a context will be called and generate the NPE.

Comment: Link : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext%28%29

Comment: You misunderstood the link. This is the impl inherited by Activity.

Comment: `return mBase.getApplicationContext();` click --> `public abstract Context  getApplicationContext();` :D

Comment: Found some time to walk through the code - why is how, better :)

Comment: More help, if you want to set up your buttons in this activity, you should set them up in a function outside of onCreate and then call that set up function after `context = getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 11):

Just to get a feeling of what's going on. *Activity* [extends ContextThemeWrapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java?av=f#642) which extends *ContextWrapper* from whom *Activity* inherits `getApplicationContext()`. *ContextWrapper* [implements it as](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext%28%29) :

```
@Override
public Context  getApplicationContext() {
    return mBase.getApplicationContext(); // mBase is a Context
}
```

The [only public constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#56) of `ContextWrapper` is :

```
 public  ContextWrapper(Context base) {
     mBase = base;
 }
```

in `ContextThemeWrapper` [we have](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.java#37) :

```
 public  ContextThemeWrapper() {
     super(null);
 }
```

and since *Activity* does not define an explicit constructor the constructor above is called - `mBase == null` in Activity's constructor - boom.

<sub>Links from `4.2.2_r1`</sub>