# calling an external method in android?

Tags: android

i'm android beginner ,i'm trying this code in basics of inheritance to get a message from void function class A and make it shows but i can't ... show me this message java.lang.nullpointerexeption... this is the cod of the class A and main activity ... and thank you :

A.java :

```
public class A extends Activity {

    public void showA(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Class A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button show_a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Show_A);

        show_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    A c=new A();
                    c.showA();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: post the code of showA() function.

Comment: I think your problem is that Context of Class A is null

Comment: You have to paste your stacktrace in case you want some help, and if you look in your trace you can find where is the problem. Then you can maybe learn how to solve you problem for example this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep

Comment: Don't ever try to create an `Activity` using `new` - it will not work and your code will fail. The Android `Activity` class is a special case class managed by the OS. You should also never attempt to create fields or methods in an `Activity` and attempt to access them from other application components (such as other Activities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass Context from Activity:

```
 A c=new A(getApplicationContext());
                c.showA();
```

Change your class A:

```
public class A {

Context c;
public A(Context c) {
    this.c=c;
}

public void showA(){
    Toast.makeText(c, "Class A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try change class A to:

```
public class A{
   public void showA(Context ctx){
   Toast.makeText(ctx, "Class A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button show_a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Show_A);

show_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            A c=new A();
            c.showA(MainActivity.this);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }
});
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the Activity A the wrong way. Activities are managed by Android so you don't create an Activity, you notify system to launch an Activity. And the way you notify Android is using **Intents**.

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then you could show the Toast in the **onResume** of your A Activity.

```
 @Override
 public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     showA();
 }
```

Or you could change the class A like @imperator_sp said

Answer (score 0):

Well what you are doing here is good according to Java but when it comes to android, it is not a good practice. What you can do here is, DON'T extend class A with `Activity` and just replace the method `showA()` with the one mentioned below:

```
public static void showA(Context context, String text){
    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and call this method from wherever you want like this:-

```
showA(this, "Class A");
```