# Android where to declare SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Im trying to use edittexts on my second activity to change strings on my first/main activity. So to do that, one must use SharedPreferences.

At the top of my second activity, I had declared them and an editor. It causes a nullpointexception error and crashes the code. I'm not sure where to initalize this as I want the sharedPreferences to be looked at in the main/first activity.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

Also, is this proper code to put in the sharedprefs dictionary?

```
if(!introstring.isEmpty()) //if the fields are NOT empty, they should get saved.
{
  editor.putString("intro", introstring);
}
```

Comment: could you post the first and second activity code ?? 
the shared preferences declared in oncreate method of the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the top of my second activity

You mean as fields - yes this will cause a NPE for reasons explained in [Why getApplicationContext() in constructor of Activity throws null pointer exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep)

So as suggested in the comments you need to

```
class YourSecondActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences sp;
    Editor e;

    protected void onCreate() {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // forget about
        // named preferences - get the default ones and finish with it
        e = sp.edit();
    }

    meth() {
        //...
        if(!introstring.isEmpty()) { // save the fields if NOT empty
            e.putString("intro", introstring);
            e.commit(); // you forgot to commit
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My way of handling SharedPrefrences is to create a class that will extend Application class and put SharedPrefrences there so that will be accessible everywhere in the app.

```
class MyApp extends Application{
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

      public void onCreate() {
           sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      }

      public static getSharedPrefrences(){
           return sharedPrefrences;
      }
}
```

you have to put declare the name tag of the application in the activity tag

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".fundamentals.UploadApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ....
    ....
</application>
```

Then, you can access it from any Activity that you want.

```
class SomeActivity extends Activity{
      onCreate(){
          SharedPrefences prefs = MyApp.getSharedPrefrences();
      }
}
```

also, you need to commit the change after you have put something in the SharedPrefrences

```
if(!introstring.isEmpty()) //if the fields are NOT empty, they should get saved.
{
  editor.putString("intro", introstring).commit();
}
```

Comment: This is a solution that I find better. I was trying to make my application wide preferences available in the Application Class and the key was to instantiate it from within the onCreate() lifecycle callback method. If you do it from an activity, then you will need to instantiate it from every single activity. It's better to create once and use many times than to re-create something every time you need it again.