# loading and saving SharedPreferences from methods

Tags: android, methods, sharedpreferences

My intention in to have a LoadPreferences and SavePreferences method. I want it to be as flexible as possible so I can request any "savable" data be called whenever I need it and saved when I'm done changing it any ANY Class/Method. When I set it up like any returnable variable, it gives me a nullpointerexception. Here is what I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Add SharedPreference loader

int mPlayerCharisma = SharedPrefLoader("playerCharisma", 0); //I want variable
// playerCharisma if it exists, and to default to int 0 if it does not
int mPlayerBusiness = SharedPrefLoader("playerBusiness", 0);
int mPlayerCombat = SharedPrefLoader("playerCombat", 0);
int mPlayerLevel = SharedPrefLoader("playerLevel", 0);
int mPlayerLocation = SharedPrefLoader("playerLocation", 0);
int mPlayerMoney = SharedPrefLoader("playerMoney", 500);
int mPlayerEnergy = SharedPrefLoader("playerEnergy", 10);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // ...
    }

    public int SharedPrefLoader(String key, int defValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("drudlordmt",
            MODE_PRIVATE); //This is where  my nullpointerexception points to//
        int returnedValue = sharedPref.getInt(key, defValue);
        return returnedValue;
    }

    public void SharedPrefSaver(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("druglordmt", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt(key, value).commit();
    }
}
```

From my reading I understand I'll need to pass my context somehow, but I want to make sure I can still do what I'm intending. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move :

```
int mPlayerCharisma = SharedPrefLoader("playerCharisma", 0); //I want variable
// playerCharisma if it exists, and to default to int 0 if it does not
int mPlayerBusiness = SharedPrefLoader("playerBusiness", 0);
int mPlayerCombat = SharedPrefLoader("playerCombat", 0);
int mPlayerLevel = SharedPrefLoader("playerLevel", 0);
int mPlayerLocation = SharedPrefLoader("playerLocation", 0);
int mPlayerMoney = SharedPrefLoader("playerMoney", 500);
int mPlayerEnergy = SharedPrefLoader("playerEnergy", 10);
```

(and all other calls to `SharedPrefLoader()`) inside `onCreate()`. See : [Why getApplicationContext() in constructor of Activity throws null pointer exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep)