# Android Java SQLite NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having some trouble when trying to get the SQLite database and execute SQL statement.

DatabaseAdapter.java

```
protected static final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}

public DatabaseAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "Database Created");
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.e(TAG, "Database Open");
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return mDb;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat
                                                // window
// destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "schoolAssignment";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private final Context mContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    // If database not exists copy it from the assets
    Log.e(TAG, "CreateDataBase()");
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            // Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}

// Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Database
// Name
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    Log.e("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}

// Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

// Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
    // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Exercise.java

```
TableLayout table_layout;

private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public Exercise(){
    this.mDb =  new DataBaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();  
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);       
    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
    BuildTable();
}

private void BuildTable() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM exercise";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int rows = mCur.getCount();
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();
                    // outer for loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                        // inner for loop
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tv.setTextSize(18);
                            tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                            tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));
                            row.addView(tv);

                        }
                        table_layout.addView(row);
                    }
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
```

And here is the error message as my LogCat:

```
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.nyp.project/edu.nyp.project.Exercise}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at edu.nyp.project.Exercise.<init>(Exercise.java:29)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
07-30 09:00:04.251: E/AndroidRuntime(16151):    ... 11 more
```

The problem lies with the empty constructor in Exercise class. When I remove it, it runs perfectly. I not sure why it behaved in this way. Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't create any constructors for your `Activity`. Put any initialization inside `onCreate()`. The reason you get `null` is because the `Context` is still null.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep

Comment: @AndrewT Do you have any ideas on how to fit it into my problem?

Comment: Are you using an existing SQLite database file? Currently, as the error says, there is no "exercise" table inside the database, which I assume something wrong happens and the database is empty.

Comment: I created a database from SQLite browser and put it into the assets folder of my project. Am I doing in the right way?

Comment: I see, that's alright. However, it seems that the DB is not copied into the app's data. I'm not sure, but try adding `DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this); dbAdapter.createDatabase();` before `this.mDb = ...`.

Comment: @AndrewT. It shows the database is created in my LogCat. But the problem still persist.

Comment: You original problem, the NPE, is solved. As for the missing table problem, this would be a new problem; consider asking it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
this.mDb =  new DataBaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
```

in the constructor because the Activity Context doesn't exist. That Line has to be in the onCreate() or onResume() or onStart() Method.

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);       
    this.mDb =  new DataBaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();  ///This Line
    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
    BuildTable();
}
```

Comment: If I move the line into the onCreate(), it throws me null pointer exception error.

Comment: @20Cents I'd move it into `onCreate()` and check the error again. Perhaps the error is caused by different source now. (Same `NullPointerException`, but different source).

Comment: @AndrewT. I've removed the two constructors in the Exercise class and modified the code as the one you provided. And now, the error messages are as the LogCat in Edited portion. Can you please help me take a look?