# Android nullpointer at listView.setAdapter()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

During my onCreate method in my main activity, I want to set adapter to a listview like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNom);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm getting a nullpointer exception at

```
list.setAdapter()
```

because list is null after

```
list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
```

I assume that calling a method on any null object will cause problems; how can I get around this? should the ListView be populated with stuff? am I not instantiating the ListView object properly?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ciltkick.nom/com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/msg"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="addNom"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure ListView exist in `activity_main.xml` with `list_item` id?

Comment: I guess you're referring to 'list items' instead of referring to the list itself.

Comment: why `this.findViewById` for only list?

Comment: because I was trying it out to see if it fixed the problem, my bad for not changing it back before posting; post edited

Comment: @sqlbuddy can u try my answer?

Comment: @Deepzz; tried it out but no change. my issue was coming from fragments getting mixed up with activities in the layout

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with calling `getApplicationContext` in `onCreate`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep).

As a solution, you can just do this :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
```

Comment: Can the person down-voting this answer explain the reason ? Or is someone unable to take criticism ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it was due to poor fragment structure in the layout; the code about was fine. Thanks!