# mContext Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got this error when start SplashScreenActivity :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LpPz.jpg)

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thank you

--> "onCreate code on SplashScreenActivity"

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable  Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        if (!NetworkManager.isInternetConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
            this.SPLASH_DELAY = 1000;
        }
        EventsHelper.INSTANCE.addEvent(this, SplashScreenActivityKt.TAG);
        NotificationUtilKt.openPlayStoreFromNotificationClick((Activity) this);
    }
```

--> "onCreate code on BaseActivity"

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        // this.job = JobKt.Job$default((Job) null, 1, (Object) null);
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        KeyboardUtilKt.hideKeyboard(this);
    }
```

Comment: your application context may be null, you could try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004891/why-getapplicationcontext-in-constructor-of-activity-throws-null-pointer-excep

Answer (score -1):

```
    KeyboardUtilKt.hideKeyboard(this); try to check hideKeyboard method or function have any null safety or not. look like context null checker with java and kotlin code.`
```

please add more details